# Change Numric Aatch in Javascript to Accept Dots

Tags: javascript, validation

Right now, I'm using this to check if a certain value is numeric:

```
(variable.match(/^[\d]*$/ ))
```

How could I modify that code so it will accept a "." or period. I looked at other websites, and I couldn't seem to find anything that would let it accept a "." without accepting letters. Answers are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(variable.match(/^[\d]*(\.\d+)?$/ ))`
this would accept number with or without dot... but if there is a dot - there must be a number after it

this strings are all valid: 01, 12.3, .23, 12, .3 ....

this strings are invalid: 12. (with the dot), 1.1.1

hope I helped...

Answer (score 1):

This will also work but it doesn't require a number after the dot (depending on your requirements)

```
(variable.match(/[0-9]+\.?([0-9]+?)?/))
```

Comment: the dot in your regex would refer to any character to that strings like "1:1" for example will also return true - you should backslash the dot...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that regex will fail you because it will match an empty string.

However if you want to match numbers and periods (and not empty strings) do this:

```
(variable.match(/^[\d.]+$/))
```

Just be aware that this will match things like:

```
`1234.234.34....1234..3`
```

If your requirements don't allow this, please give us some more information about what your requirements are.

Cheers

Comment: No need to escape `.` inside a character class.

Comment: @ThiefMaster After all these years I only just recently learned that and have had a hard time getting used to it!  Thanks for the reminder, answer updated.